# How can I change de size of a field in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table defined as follow:

```
def self.up
 create_table "equipes", :primary_key => "equipe_id", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "equipe_nom",                   :limit => 30,   :null => false
  t.string   "equipe_nom_pseudo",    :limit => 8,    :null => false
  t.string   "equipe_manager",       :limit => 40
  t.string   "equipe_telephone_1",   :limit => 22
  t.string   "equipe_adresse_email", :limit => 50
  t.string   "equipe_responsable",   :limit => 50

  t.timestamps
end
```

I want to change the limit of the field "equipe_nom" from 30 to 150.

What are the best way to do that?

Can I use RAKE G MIGRATION .... ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Don't confuse the `rake` command with the `rails` command. `Rake` is a command that will run tasks a little more advanced than the make command. `rails` is a command provided by the rails framework to, for instance, create an app, generate migrations, etc. You will get a list of all `rails` commands and their effect by just typing `rails` in the terminal without parameters. `rails g migration migrationname` will generate a migration for you. Read more about migrations [in this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

With that out of the way, there are two possibilities to solve your problem:

- If you have already run this migration before and it was your last migration, you will need to run `rake db:rollback`, then change the value in your migration file that you showed above, save it, and then run `rake db:migrate` again. This will first reverse the last migration (in this case, drop the table "equipes"), and then run it again with your changes.
- If this is an older migration, you can create a new one by doing `rails g migration change_equipe_nom_to_limit_150`. Look at the file it created. Inside `def up` write: `change_column :equipes, :equipe_nom, :string, :limit => 150`. Save the file, run `rake db:migrate`

If you are not sure which case applies, just do the second one. It will always work.

Comment: Thanks very much to your answer Charles. I have made attention error between rails and rake but I understand each of one.  I have tested your last solution and all working fine. Unfortunally, the rails migration guide doesn't give examples for this kind of migration.